# SampleSyncAdapter - username/password

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to run SampleSyncAdapter project that is in
   http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html
   but i can log in. In here
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ac875a97679122f0?pli=1 
they says that use user1/test(I understand that username:user1,password:test) but when i try it, I cant log in. Any idea how I can use that project?
Ty All...

Answer (score 0):

user1/test works for me. I'm running Android 4.0 sample. However, even though login works, the sync doesn't: the contacts aren't downloaded when I click on the **sync** button.

Comment: one more information: though log in is successful, the sync didn't happen: no any contacts has been down loaded after click on "sync" icon.